# Running Angular JS UnitTests with Karma and Chutzpah

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, chutzpah

Can I run my AngularJS Unit Tests with Karma and Chutzpah? Is that possible?

I am coding my Unit TestCases in Visual Studio and have already installed Chutzpah so whether I can install Karma also?

I need Karma as I need to include some template urls

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both but you would need to setup both a Karma config and a chutzpah.json config.

Comment: Whether I can still use Visual studio to execute testcases?

Comment: Yes, if you have configured chutzpah to run your tests you can with the Chutzpah extensions.